# Python sys.path.append with modules shadowing each other

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, path, gae-module

I am trying to import module named "google" from a custom folder (inside google_appengine folder).

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/sashko/WebProgramming/google_appengine")
import google.appengine.api
```

But there is already a module named "google" in sys.path:

```
import google
print google.__path__

['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google']
```

And it shadows module "google" from the custom folder. What would you suggest in such cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert the path *at the start* of `sys.modules`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/sashko/WebProgramming/google_appengine")
```

Now the `google_appengine` directory will be consulted before the `dist-packages`  location.